# How to use Brave web browser with python, selenium and chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, brave, brave-browser

I switched from Google's Chrome to [Brave web browser](https://brave.com/) and am having a hard time getting it to work with Brave like it did with Chrome. Brave is based on chromium so I guessed it should not be that hard. I made sure that my Brave and Chromedriver are on the same version like this,

```sh
~/some/path $ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024})
```

My chromedriver is also in `/user/bin`,

```sh
~/path $ cd /usr/bin/
/usr/bin $ ls | grep chromedriver
chromedriver
```

And to check the Brave version, I get: `Version 0.68.132 Chromium: 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Then I run this code,

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/brave-browser')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.close()
```

This opens a Brave window but then instead of getting the page the driver is pointed to, an exception is thrown,

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscrap.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/brave-browser')
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/brave-browser unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work:

Try this python script (python3.7)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
# option.add_argument("--incognito") OPTIONAL
# option.add_argument("--headless") OPTIONAL

# Create new Instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

cheers.

Answer (score 8):

The `executable_path` key is used to pass the absolute path of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) binary i.e. the *chromedriver* executable.

To initiate a *Brave* browser session additionally you have to pass the absolute location of the *brave-browser* binary through the **`binary_location`** argument of an instance of `ChromeOptions`.

So the effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
brave_path = '/usr/bin/brave-browser'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium on Windows 10 system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310119/deprecationwarning-use-options-instead-of-chrome-options-error-using-chromedriv/63310208#63310208)
- [How to initiate Brave browser using Selenium and Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626853/how-to-initiate-brave-browser-using-selenium-and-python-on-windows/62627392#62627392)
- [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using Brave Browser With Python Selenium and Chromedriver on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029629/deprecationwarning-use-options-instead-of-chrome-options-error-using-brave-brow/65030107#65030107)

Answer (score 2):

This also works in windows 10 with Brave browser.  I downloaded Chromedriver and put it in the folder with Brave.exe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = "C:\\Users\\5150s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

Comment: Make sure to download the driver that matches your Brave browser. Go to "About Brave" and look for the Chromium driver version, e.g. Chromium: 91.0.4472.164, then select that version from the Chromium download site: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above gave me some errors. This code removes the executable path and options errors.
Chromedriver is in the pycharm folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver_path = "C:/Users/johnm/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

s=Service(driver_path)
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=option)
browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Selenium 4.15.2, apparently there is not anymore a need to create a Service.
At least, on my Ubuntu installation (23), I could get Brave opened just using the following code.

```
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.binary_location = "/opt/brave.com/brave/brave"

    browser = Chrome(options=options)
```

Still I can't figure out how to attach to the currently running session rather than opening a brand new testing session window.