# DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium on Windows 10 system

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to run this code on my windows 10 machine https://github.com/KalleHallden/reddit_automations/blame/master/movie-tickets.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from decouple import config
import time

# the way to locate the button or thing you want on a website in chrome is
# by pressing cmd + shift + c and then you can use your mouse to find the 
# info on the element that you want and you can copy the full xpath.

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
# options.add_argument('--incognito')
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/kalle/Downloads/chromedriver83", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(config('THEATRE_SITE'))
# for some odd reason you need to reload the site for it to load.
# possibly a bug of the theatre site
driver.get(config('THEATRE_SITE'))
time.sleep(3)
# select city
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/label/input')
button.click()

# save city
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/span/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(2)

# proceed to tickets tab
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/nav/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a')
button.click()
time.sleep(2)

# select the movie you want (should be more specific than just selecting the first one but whateva)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li/div/div[1]/div/span[2]/a')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)

# select the time you want to go
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/div/span/span[3]/span[2]/span')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)

# choose amount of people
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(2)

# choose seats
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(2)

# pay
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/div[4]/div/div[2]/button/span')
button.click()
```

I have all the correct programs installed:

- running python 3.8
- have chrome webdriver installed
- running version 84 stable chrome web browser

When I run the program it opens chrome however I get a blank web page with nothing on there but some text which says "data:." that is all nothing else.

This is the error I get in VS code:

```
:\Users\user>python c:/chromedriver_win32/movie-tickets1.py
c:/chromedriver_win32/movie-tickets1.py:15: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:29442/devtools/browser/872d4312-b51d-4a38-bc1b-3b80495950
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/chromedriver_win32/movie-tickets1.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver.get(config("https://www.google.co.uk"))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\decouple.py", line 68, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: https://www.google.co.uk not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am unsure why decouple is not working.

Answer (score 18):

This error message...

```
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
```

...implies that in your program you have used `chrome_options` to initiate a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context*.

`chrome_options` is deprecated now and you have to use `options` instead as well as pass the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* along with the extension.

---

### Solution

As you are triggering your tests on a [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system, effectively you line of code will be:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Comment: this was the fix for the issue "driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',options = options"                               however i still cannot get the program to show the website, any ideas?, i keep getting the error as stated in the first post about declaring something as env variable

Comment: @Ali Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?

Answer (score 10):

It's ok!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

no, the error will remain if you cover it like this

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

it will be right

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Below code sample is from 2022 and uses Web Driver Manager (https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

```
#Imports for Web Driver, Service, Web Driver Manager

   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#options reference to Chrome Options

   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

#Pass options to the WebDriver with ChromeDriverManager

     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are now seeing `WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'`, this is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

`chrome_options` has been removed. Also, the driver manager is now built-in to selenium, so you no longer need to use the separate `webdriver_manager`. The Selenium Team talked about that here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-manager-best-tool-from-you-can-forget-david-burns/

Use the `service` and `options` args for passing in settings:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

---

NOTE: Someone incorrectly closed [WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument chrome_options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76736724/7058266) as a duplicate and pointed to this page as having answers, but it's not the same question. This solution answers the question marked as a duplicate.