# ChromeDriver not opening new page with chrome_options parameter

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I'm trying to use the following code to open a new page using ChromeDriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path of chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
```

I still get the `"DevTools listening on...."` print but no new page is being opened. If however I run:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"path")
```

without the chrome_options parameter, the page opens. Not sure why this is?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Note that you're using `headless` in your options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome_options` was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310208/7429447) long back.

```
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
```

you have to use an instance of `options` instead as well as pass the absolute path of the ChromeDriver along with the extension as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path of chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
#object of ChromeOptions
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#add option
op.add_argument('--enable-extensions')
#pass option to webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=op)
```