# I am getting error in my script to scrape the GoodRead page?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I tried my ways to scrape without opening the browser, but I am getting this error when I changed to use headless that helps not open the web browser to scrape the data:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abid.alam/Desktop/upsc_newnew.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)  # Notice chrome_options instead of options
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'
```

And here is my Python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Create Chrome driver with ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)  # Notice chrome_options instead of options

# Define the URL to scrape for the current page
url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20656089-indian-polity"

# Get the HTML content of the page
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), '...more')]/parent::a")))

# Click the "..more" button
more_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '...more')]/parent::a")
more_button.click()

# Get the HTML content of the page after clicking the button
page_content = driver.page_source

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the image tag based on its attributes
book_image_element = soup.find("img", {"class": "ResponsiveImage"})

if book_image_element:
    # Get the image source (src) attribute
    book_image_url = book_image_element.get("src")
else:
    book_image_url = "Image not available"

# Find the element with the specified data-testid attribute
description_element = soup.find("div", {"data-testid": "description"})

# Extract the text content using the HTML structure
if description_element:
    span_element = description_element.find("div", class_="DetailsLayoutRightParagraph").find("span", class_="Formatted")
    if span_element:
        description_text = span_element.get_text()
    else:
        description_text = "Description not available within the expected structure."
else:
    description_text = "Description element not found in the HTML."

# Extract all genre names
genre_names = []
genres_element = soup.find("div", {"data-testid": "genresList"})
if genres_element:
    genre_buttons = genres_element.find_all("span", class_="Button__labelItem")
    genre_names = [genre.get_text() for genre in genre_buttons]

# Combine the scraped data into a DataFrame
data = {
    'Book Image URL': [book_image_url],
    'Description': [description_text],
    'Genre': [', '.join(genre_names)]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
excel_filename = 'book_data.xlsx'
df.to_excel(excel_filename, index=False)

print("Data saved to", excel_filename)
```

with the below code I am able to scrape but browser will open that I want to avoid not to open the browser during scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # Import WebDriverWait

# Create Chrome driver with ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Define the URL to scrape for the current page
url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20656089-indian-polity"

# Get the HTML content of the page
page = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the image tag based on its attributes
book_image_element = soup.find("img", {"class": "ResponsiveImage"})

if book_image_element:
    # Get the image source (src) attribute
    book_image_url = book_image_element.get("src")
else:
    book_image_url = "Image not available"

# Find the element with the specified data-testid attribute
description_element = soup.find("div", {"data-testid": "description"})

# Extract the text content using the HTML structure
if description_element:
    span_element = description_element.find("div", class_="DetailsLayoutRightParagraph").find("span", class_="Formatted")
    if span_element:
        description_text = span_element.get_text()
    else:
        description_text = "Description not available within the expected structure."
else:
    description_text = "Description element not found in the HTML."

# Open the page in the browser
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the "..more" button to be clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "...more")]')))

# Click the "..more" button
more_button.click()

# Get the HTML content of the page after clicking the button
page_content = driver.page_source

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the element with the specified data-testid attribute
genres_element = soup.find("div", {"data-testid": "genresList"})

# Extract all genre names
genre_names = []
if genres_element:
    genre_buttons = genres_element.find_all("span", class_="Button__labelItem")
    genre_names = [genre.get_text() for genre in genre_buttons]

# Combine the scraped data into a DataFrame
data = {
    'Book Image URL': [book_image_url],
    'Description': [description_text],
    'Genre': [', '.join(genre_names)]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
excel_filename = 'book_data.xlsx'
df.to_excel(excel_filename, index=False)

print("Data saved to", excel_filename)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome\_options error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium on Windows 10 system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310119/deprecationwarning-use-options-instead-of-chrome-options-error-using-chromedriv)

Comment: That said, why not use their API, instead of screen-scraping

Comment: @buran "As of December 8th 2020, Goodreads no longer issues new developer keys for our public developer API and plans to retire the current version of these tools."

https://www.goodreads.com/api

Comment: @Pragmatick, thank you. I didn't know that (i.e. I knew they have API, but not that they stopped issuing new developer keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_genres(soup):
    genres = []
    for a in soup.select('a[href*="/genres/"]'):
        genres.append(a.text)
    return genres


def scrape_book(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    book = {
        "title": soup.find(
            "h1", {"class": "Text Text__title1", "data-testid": "bookTitle"}
        ).text,
        "description": soup.find("span", {"class": "Formatted"}).text,
        "genres": get_genres(soup),
    }

    return book


b = scrape_book("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20656089-indian-polity")
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "title": "Indian Polity",
    "description": "Indian Polity by M. Laxmikanth needs no introduction. It is one of the most popular and comprehensive books on the subject and has been a consistent bestseller for many years. It has become a must-read book for aspirants appearing in various competitive examinations especially the civil services examinations. The wide range and scope of issues that it covers, also make it valuable to postgraduates, research scholars, academicians, researchers and general readers who would like to be well informed of the country's political and constitutional issues.",
    "genres": [
        "India",
        "Nonfiction",
        "Politics",
        "Academic",
        "History",
        "Law",
        "Indian Literature",
    ],
}
```