# Bokeh: Set default browser to Brave

Tags: python, browser, bokeh, default

how to set Bokeh to use Brave as default browser..

tried

```
 bokeh.settings.settings.browser.set_value('/usr/bin/brave-browser')
```

still get

```
 Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Comment: Maybe you should check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver). Bokeh [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver) is using pythons [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Bokeh just calls out to the Python stdlib `webbrowser.open` which does not currently know about Brave, apparently. There is nothing we can do about that, so for now you will need to resort to a selenium solution.