# Unable to use webdriver with Brave Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner in Python and Selenium, and I dont know what is the error in my code or environment.
How to solve this problem?

app.py:-

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://github.com")
```

Error:-

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x0025D953+2414931]
        Ordinal0 [0x001EF5E1+1963489]
        Ordinal0 [0x000DC6B8+837304]
        Ordinal0 [0x000F7A8E+948878]
        Ordinal0 [0x000F5FB1+942001]
        Ordinal0 [0x00129100+1151232]
        Ordinal0 [0x00128D5A+1150298]
        Ordinal0 [0x001242B6+1131190]
        Ordinal0 [0x000FE860+976992]
        Ordinal0 [0x000FF756+980822]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x004CCC62+2510274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x004BF760+2455744]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x002EEABA+551962]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x002ED916+547446]
        Ordinal0 [0x001F5F3B+1990459]
        Ordinal0 [0x001FA898+2009240]
        Ordinal0 [0x001FA985+2009477]
        Ordinal0 [0x00203AD1+2046673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7631FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77877A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77877A4E+238]
        (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver check this out

Answer (score 0):

***To initiate a Brave browser session additionally you have to pass the absolute location of the brave-browser binary through the binary_location argument of an instance of ChromeOptions.***

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
# option.add_argument("--incognito") OPTIONAL
# option.add_argument("--headless") OPTIONAL

# Create new Instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

**Note:- Add chromedriver to path to access it without typing Location.**

**For More Details, Have a look at this Link**

[How to use Brave web browser with python, selenium and chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver)

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass chromedriver.exe path

```
chromedriver_path = C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe # this is example path you haveto pass your downloaded chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "Enter your chromedriver path")
driver.get("https://github.com")
```

2. You have to download chromedriver and put it in your python file's folder. Then you don't need to pass chromedriver path.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://github.com")
```