# How to install browser extension for namely brave, through terminal?

Tags: bash, google-chrome-extension, browser, terminal

I was writing a script that sets up my entire linux setup after a fresh install. I was looking into how to install the extensions that I use without having to install them from the chrome extension store.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```bash
echo "### Installing bitwarden browser plugin"
BITWARDEN_ID=nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb
EXTENSIONS_PATH=/opt/brave.com/brave/extensions
mkdir -p $EXTENSIONS_PATH
echo '{ "external_update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" }' > "${EXTENSIONS_PATH}/${BITWARDEN_ID}.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using selenium for that, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver#:~:text=from%20selenium%20import%20webdriver%20driver%20%3D%20webdriver.Chrome%20%28executable_path%3D%27%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fbrave-browser%27%29,driver%20is%20pointed%20to%2C%20an%20exception%20is%20thrown%2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver#:%7E:text=from%20selenium%20import%20webdriver%20driver%20%3D%20webdriver.Chrome%20%28executable_path%3D%27%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fbrave-browser%27%29,driver%20is%20pointed%20to%2C%20an%20exception%20is%20thrown%2C) I think will be helpful in helping you on Linux.